# python subprocess.call failing with FileNotFoundError

Tags: python, subprocess

In my python script I am trying to change the permissions of a csv file after having finished writing onto it. But my subprocess.call fails with error `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'chmod': 'chmod'`

Please help me here to know what I am doing wrong.

**Error**

```
File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1364, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'sudo': 'sudo'
```

**Python code:**

```
def create_responsecsv(batchid,fname):
        try:
                connection = connect_DB()
                cur = connection.cursor()
                ids = str(batchid)
                sql = "SELECT query here WHERE SOME_ID= "+ids
                print(sql)
                cur.execute(sql)
                rows = cur.fetchall()
logging.info('rows',rows)
                if rows:
                        response_filename = fname.replace("RQ","RS")
file_path=cfg.XFBFolderResponse
file_name=response_filename
actual_file=file_path+file_name
                        writer = csv.writer(open(cfg.XFBFolderResponse + response_filename,"w"))
                        writer.writerow(['Old Device id','Old Company','New Item id','New Item','Device Type','New Item IP Address','Status'])
                        for x in rows:
                                writer.writerow(x)                                                                                                
                        subprocess.call(['chmod', '0777', actual_file])                                                                                
        except cx_Oracle.Error as e:
                print(e)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about [chmod](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chmod) ? Why should you run `subprocess.call(...)`

```
os.chmod(actual_file, 0o0777)
```

Comment: sorry @balderman it's a maintenance code... what is the different between two? should i use os straightaway?

Comment: @raikumardipak if you have a built-in solution in python - what is the point in forking an external process?